# Data Manipulation either in MATLAB or Python

Tags: python, matlab, data-manipulation

I want to manipulate data of text file either in MATLAB or python. My data file contains 3000 rows but I have posted here for just as an example of 4 rows of data. The data file has R, L, G, C data for different frequencies (here 3 frequency in 3 rows). Now I want to manipulate the data to another format (Let's say, the target file).

Now, Can anyone help me with what is the command or loop command that I need for manipulate the data for 3000 frequencies and at the end, to save it as new target text file.

The data file is:

```
FORMAT Freq R1:1    R1:2    R2:1    R2:2    L1:1    L1:2    L2:1    L2:2    G1:1    G1:2    G2:1    G2:2    C1:1    C1:2    C2:1    C2:2
0.00E+00    5.11E+00    7.13E-13    7.13E-13    5.11E+00    6.61E-07    4.46E-07    4.46E-07    6.61E-07    1.04E-17    -5.02E-18   -5.02E-18   1.04E-17    5.58E-11    -3.27E-11   -3.27E-11   5.58E-11
1.00E+06    5.59E+00    9.82E-03    9.82E-03    5.59E+00    6.97E-07    4.47E-07    4.47E-07    6.97E-07    6.42E-07    -3.11E-07   -3.11E-07   6.42E-07    5.54E-11    -3.25E-11   -3.25E-11   5.54E-11
2.00E+06    5.69E+00    2.47E-02    2.47E-02    5.69E+00    7.06E-07    4.48E-07    4.48E-07    7.06E-07    1.29E-06    -6.23E-07   -6.23E-07   1.29E-06    5.53E-11    -3.25E-11   -3.25E-11   5.53E-11
```

and target file is:

```
FORMAT Freq :   R1:1    R1:2    R2:1    R2:2
        L1:1    L1:2    L2:1    L2:2
        G1:1    G1:2    G2:1    G2:2
        C1:1    C1:2    C2:1    C2:2

0.00E+00    :   5.11E+00    7.13E-13    7.13E-13    5.11E+00
        6.61E-07    4.46E-07    4.46E-07    6.61E-07
        1.04E-17    -5.02E-18   -5.02E-18   1.04E-17
        5.58E-11    -3.27E-11   -3.27E-11   5.58E-11

1.00E+06    :   5.59E+00    9.82E-03    9.82E-03    5.59E+00
        6.97E-07    4.47E-07    4.47E-07    6.97E-07
        6.42E-07    -3.11E-07   -3.11E-07   6.42E-07
        5.54E-11    -3.25E-11   -3.25E-11   5.54E-11

2.00E+06    :   5.69E+00    2.47E-02    2.47E-02    5.69E+00
        7.06E-07    4.48E-07    4.48E-07    7.06E-07
        1.29E-06    -6.23E-07   -6.23E-07   1.29E-06
        5.53E-11    -3.25E-11   -3.25E-11   5.53E-11
```

I am using Anaconda (Spyder) for python package (which includes python 3.6.4). The code looks like what @xg.plt.py suggested which gives error because data is stored as strings. So I tried to change data type in different ways and it is giving me different errors. My code is given below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Data_file.txt')
#df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
#df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
#df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
#df = df.infer_objects()
df = df.astype(float)

formatters = {col : ('{:.2e}\n'.format if col[-3:]=='2:2' else '{:.2e}'.format) for col in df.columns}
formatters[df.columns[0]] = '{:.2e} : '.format
header_formatters = {col : ('{} \n'.format if col[-3:]=='2:2' else '{} '.format) for col in df.columns}
header_formatters[df.columns[0]] = '{} : '.format

f = open('formatted.txt','w')
f.write(''.join([header_formatters[col](col) for col in df.columns])+'\n')
df.to_string(buf=f,formatters=formatters,header=False,index=False)
f.close()
```

If I don't change data type it gives me error like below:

```
ValueError: Unknown format code 'e' for object of type 'str'
```

If I use `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')` or `df = df.infer_objects()` it gives me same error like above `ValueError: Unknown format code 'e' for object of type 'str'`

If I use `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` it runs but it coerce all the value to NaN in first column and results in formatted file like below:

```
FORMAT Freq R1:1    R1:2    R2:1    R2:2    L1:1    L1:2    L2:1    L2:2    G1:1    G1:2    G2:1    G2:2    C1:1    C1:2    C2:1    C2:2 : 
nan : 
nan : 
nan :
```

if I use `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)` it give me following error:

```
ValueError: ('Unable to parse string "0.00E+00\t5.11E+00\t7.13E-13\t7.13E-13\t5.11E+00\t6.61E-07\t4.46E-07\t4.46E-07\t6.61E-07\t1.04E-17\t-5.02E-18\t-5.02E-18\t1.04E-17\t5.58E-11\t-3.27E-11\t-3.27E-11\t5.58E-11" at position 0', 'occurred at index FORMAT Freq\tR1:1\tR1:2\tR2:1\tR2:2\tL1:1\tL1:2\tL2:1\tL2:2\tG1:1\tG1:2\tG2:1\tG2:2\tC1:1\tC1:2\tC2:1\tC2:2')
```

When I type `df.dtypes`to check the dataframe type it gives me following result:

```
FORMAT Freq\tR1:1\tR1:2\tR2:1\tR2:2\tL1:1\tL1:2\tL2:1\tL2:2\tG1:1\tG1:2\tG2:1\tG2:2\tC1:1\tC1:2\tC2:1\tC2:2    float64
dtype: object
```

if I use `df = df.astype(float)` it give me following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2.00E+06\t5.69E+00\t2.47E-02\t2.47E-02\t5.69E+00\t7.06E-07\t4.48E-07\t4.48E-07\t7.06E-07\t1.29E-06\t-6.23E-07\t-6.23E-07\t1.29E-06\t5.53E-11\t-3.25E-11\t-3.25E-11\t5.53E-11'
```

Comment: I suggest you start by defining a class or struct object that holds a "row" of data. Then another object holding a list of those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the python package [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

The first step would be to load the data into a dataframe, i.e. with `pd.read_csv()`. `pandas` has an extensive set of [I/O tools](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html).

Then, write the dataframe to a file. As the target format is quite unusual, the best option is probably to use the function `to_string` with a default formatter:

```
formatters = {col : ('{:.2e}\n'.format if col[-3:]=='2:2' else '{:.2e}'.format) for col in df.columns}
formatters[df.columns[0]] = '{:.2e} : '.format
header_formatters = {col : ('{} \n'.format if col[-3:]=='2:2' else '{} '.format) for col in df.columns}
header_formatters[df.columns[0]] = '{} : '.format
```

There is one formatter for the numeric values, and another for the header. The numeric formatter basically tells `pandas` to write the numbers in exponential notation, with 2 decimal positions, and if the column finishes with `'2:2'`, add a breakline after the number. The header formatter simply has the breakline when desired. Both write a colon after the number in the first column. See [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/) for more information.

Then, a file can be opened and the formatted string written to it:

```
f = open('filename.txt','w')
f.write(''.join([header_formatters[col](col) for col in df.columns])+'\n')
df.to_string(buf=f,formatters=formatters,header=False,index=False)
f.close()
```

The generated `filename.txt` looks like this:

```
FORMAT Freq : R1:1 R1:2 R2:1 R2:2 
L1:1 L1:2 L2:1 L2:2 
G1:1 G1:2 G2:1 G2:2 
C1:1 C1:2 C2:1 C2:2 

0.00e+00 :  5.11e+00 7.13e-13 7.13e-13 5.11e+00
6.61e-07 4.46e-07 4.46e-07 6.61e-07
1.04e-17 -5.02e-18 -5.02e-18 1.04e-17
5.58e-11 -3.27e-11 -3.27e-11 5.58e-11

1.00e+06 :  5.59e+00 9.82e-03 9.82e-03 5.59e+00
6.97e-07 4.47e-07 4.47e-07 6.97e-07
6.42e-07 -3.11e-07 -3.11e-07 6.42e-07
5.54e-11 -3.25e-11 -3.25e-11 5.54e-11

2.00e+06 :  5.69e+00 2.47e-02 2.47e-02 5.69e+00
7.06e-07 4.48e-07 4.48e-07 7.06e-07
1.29e-06 -6.23e-07 -6.23e-07 1.29e-06
5.53e-11 -3.25e-11 -3.25e-11 5.53e-11
```

Comment: thanks for your elaborated answer. I tried as you showed. But after formatting, writing the data is having the problem most probably.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Is it that the output file ia not the desired one? There is an error message? If so, then what message does this error print?

Comment: sorry for late reply as I was sick. I have updated my question with the code that you suggested and the error.

Comment: @aguntuk This error is telling you that your data is stored as strings, therefore when you try to format it in exponential notation with 2 decimals, it crashes. You should first convert them to floats and then they will be formatted as desired. This question is about this conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried many ways to convert the data type but still, error is there. I summarized the errors in the question for more clarification.

Comment: As you can see in the error message, the **whole** row is read as a string. If you take a look at the [read_csv() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv), you will see that the default separator is `,`, whereas in your case, it looks like a tab is the separator, so it should be changed to `'\s+'`.

Comment: thanks alot. It worked pretty well. Sorry to be late.